# Efficient way to de-duplicate a dataframe in R and create case weights

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

**Problem**

I have a very large data frame with ~60 columns and ~12M rows that I want to prep for training a model.

To speed-up the whole process I like to collapse the data frame, by getting only the unique rows as well as their case weights (how often they occur).

So going from this data frame:

```
V1 | V2 | V3
------------
A  | B  | A
A  | B  | A
C  | C  | A
C  | C  | A
C  | C  | A
```

to this data frame:

```
V1 | V2 | V3 | weights
----------------------
A  | B  | A  | 2
C  | C  | A  | 3
```

**Current Approach**

Currently I use `dplyr` logic to do this, which works but also takes forever:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by_all() %>% count()
```

Is there a better and especially computationally faster way? Maybe to even do this at reading in the csv and not after?

Comment: It would be easier for people to help you if you constructed your sample `df` using executable code (e.g. build it manually at your end, and use `dput()` to output code to reproduce it.  Or just show us the code for the manual construction.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your data is too big given the hardware but have you tried `data.table`?

```
library(data.table)
setDTthreads(0L)
setDT(df)[, .N, by = names(df)]

#        V1     V2     V3     N
#    <char> <char> <char> <int>
# 1:      A      B      A     2
# 2:      C      C      A     3
```

*Reproducible* data:

```
df = data.frame(
  V1 = c("A", "A", "C", "C", "C"), 
  V2 = c("B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), 
  V3 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A")
)
```

Comment: I am doing this on GCP notebooks so I have a comfy 40vCPUs and 961 GB RAM available. I am executing the code and measuring time, thanks for the tip!

Comment: This solution only took 6mins so I count it as the winner.

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(n ~ ., cbind(df, n = 1), sum)
  V1 V2 V3 n
1  A  B  A 2
2  C  C  A 3
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  count(across(everything()))
  V1 V2 V3 n
1  A  B  A 2
2  C  C  A 3
```